What is the linux / ubuntu / rhel term for Syspreping an image on Windows?
In the Windows world, you can take a VM, apply all of your software and Windows updates to it then save it as a new base image in .vhd or iso format.  We call this sysprep, and its great to allow you to deploy fully up to date VMs that are secure on first boot.
There is some degree of toil to make these and keep them up to date, but there is a huge payoff in deploying secure machines.
Is this also a concept in the Linux world?  if so, what are the terminologies and technologies that are used?

Systemback (https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/using-systemback/13062) :

Very great tool, very similar to sysprep and very easy to use.
One of the most notable features is the ability to create a live bootable and installable Linux system from your current setup, preserving all previous customizations such as wallpapers, languages, drivers & dynamically loadable modules, file systems moodifications, services, systemd preferences, network settings, and any other linux stuff.
I haven't used it in years, and I suspect it may not be maintained anymore, so it may not be compatible with all Linux distros' (works with Debian/Ubuntu but compatibility with other distros is uncertain).

live-build (https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man7/live-build.7.html):

In the Linux community, we typically prefer creating a Linux system from scratch, which may not be as difficult as it seems.
live-build is a set of scripts to  build  Debian  Live  system  images. The  idea  behind live-build  is a tool suite that uses a configuration directory to completely automate and customize all aspects of building a Live image.
The customized installable images are guaranteed to be up-to-date because the building process automatically pulls from the Linux repositories, ensuring (more-or-less) that the latest kernels and packages are included.
The firmware produced is more customized to suit your specific needs, allowing for deeper customization than Systemback. For example, you can choose which packages are included in the Linux system (or not), giving you more control over the pinciples of least privileges and minimization with tailor-made systems.

build-root or yocto (https://www.buildroot.org/) :

This is almost as deep as you can go.
Buildroot is a set of Makefiles and patches that simplifies and automates the process of building a complete and bootable Linux environment for an embedded system, while using cross-compilation to allow building for multiple target platforms on a single Linux-based development system.
Along with the same capabilities as other technologies, you have the option to add your own customized, build, and compiled Linux kernel with any desired patches. You also have the ability to create your own Board Support Package and a personalized bootloader (similar to BIOS), and even develop your own custom filesystem (typically using busybox).
Although it may be labeled as "embedded systems", the program works on almost any platform, including standard laptops. (Let's do philosophy here) A PC laptop can be viewed as an embedded system. :)

Hope it helps

There is virt-sysprep, but that's more for the "remove personalization data" aspect of sysprep. The virt-customize tool, part of the same libguestfs-tools suite, lets you run arbitrary scripts in an image (and perform a variety of other customizations).
Even without special tooling, if you have an existing image, it's relatively simple to mount it somewhere, run some scripts to perform updates/customizations, and then unmount it.
I think a more common process in the Linux world is to start with a blank image and use an installer of some sort to provision it with up-to-date packages and configuration.  For example, I've used kickstart to perform automated installations onto disk images, which I can then use as the base for deploying multple virtual machines.
There are other more general purpose tools like disk image builder that allow you to do the same thing.
Fedora uses the kiwi project to create cloud images, using definitions from this repository.
